# How to make a program using message contract in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am very very new to WCF and I have been asked to write a WCF service that will use Message Contract to generate an xml file as well as to read the xml file via the cilent proxy?

I am unable to click thru though searched in net.

If anyone can tell me the concept as well as a simple program of wCF(specific to Message contract) will be of great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/pages/windows-communication-foundation-tutorial-part-3-messaging-messagecontracts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, I would recommend you have a look at the [Pluralsight screen casts on WCF](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/browselibrary.aspx?technology=WCF) - it's an excellent series going from "[Creating your first WCF service](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/howtovideo.aspx?a=aaron-skonnard&n=creating-your-first-wcf-service)" and "[Creating your first WCF client](http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/howtovideo.aspx?a=aaron-skonnard&n=creating-your-first-wcf-client)" all the way to rather advanced topics. Aaron Skonnard very nicely explains everything in 10-15 minutes screencasts - highly recommended!

For Message contracts specifically, check out:

- [Using Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx)
- [WCF Services - Messages Contracts](http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Services%E2%80%94Message_Contracts)

The question is: do you really need message contracts?? Most of the time (> 90%), you don't - why do you want to use message contracts specifically?? I would try to learn WCF without focussing too much on the message contracts, unless you have a very specific need for them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did my first experiment on Message Contract from this site[Difference between Data Contract and Message Contract in WCF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ccbf6cb3-23dd-4e95-86a2-4ecdd390f9b1). They have given a program in the down and with a bit of my wit (joking) I was able to get thru.

But many thanks to all of you who has helped me.